# python: exception inside try doesn't jump to except

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree

I am trying to search within the EU parliment votes' description.
They are standard xml files. So far I noticed 2 versions of the votes' result: where the description is text and where it is an url.
Fails at this file: `https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/PV-9-2022-09-12-RCV_FR.xml`
Works fine on the following file: `https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/PV-9-2022-07-06-RCV_FR.xml`

My problem is not the failure itself (that's why I added the try clause) but that code execution doesn't jump to the except path, just exits here with this: `string indices must be integers`

Please help, why isn't the error properly handled?

```
for currentfile in f:
    mytree = ET.parse(xmlfiles + "\\" + currentfile)
    myroot = mytree.getroot()
    dixml = etree_to_dict(myroot)
    for votes in dixml['PV.RollCallVoteResults']['RollCallVote.Result']:
        try:
            title = votes['RollCallVote.Description.Text']  #fails here
            titletype = type(title)
            if titletype == dict:
                title=title['#text']
        except :
            title = votes['RollCallVote.Description.Text']['a']['#text']
        try:
            ltitle = title.lower()
        except :
            print(type(title))
        if stringtosearch in ltitle:
            print(title,currentfile)
```

edit:
full trace:

```
  Message=string indices must be integers
  Source=...debug.py
  StackTrace:
  File "...debug.py", line 44, in <module>
    title = votes['RollCallVote.Description.Text'] 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "...debug.py", line 44, in <module>
    title = votes['RollCallVote.Description.Text']
  File "...debug.py", line 49, in <module> (Current frame)
    title = votes['RollCallVote.Description.Text']['a']['#text']
```

Comment: Show us the full error traceback.

Comment: In except clause you are trying to access keys on a string object , this is what the error is saying.

Comment: Check the value of votes if that is a dictionary then check nested values as well

Comment: read the full trace: _"During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred"_ and it shows you the line `title = votes['RollCallVote.Description.Text']['a']['#text']`

Comment: @Anentropic: thanks, indeed, I added an extra try here and now the exception is catched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would happen if there is a new exception raised within your catch block, I would presume specifically the votes object at some point of you accessing it, raises this exception.

Try printing out votes and then each time you access it by indexing print it out you'll see to which extent you can continue accessing it via string index ( votes['string'] ).

Comment: Yes, indeed, thank you. I added and extra try in the except path and it works now. It looks like there's only one RollCallVote.Result compared to the others that have more, and this is causing the trouble.

Comment: Perfect, glad to be of help :)